# Google Firebase token not NotRegistered with Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with Firebase, i get the token with `FirebaseInstanceIdService` service with method `onTokenRefresh`

```
public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken =    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.i(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
 }
```

I take the from the Android Studio  Logcat( select it and copy/paste ) and i paste Postman tool. 
With some token I don't have problem but with other I have the error

> NotRegistered

Example of token notRegistered:

`e98tZENV-FY:APA91bEBScMMWJSDtU08ZaXy172KPSle_dC5TFPUHiZ_OCg6o03Jmk0yi288v3byLVfLVUkksGJ7m-QR2swMUPlMlmwFiPWswLrKd9UTbtdbx0l02k0OhT84YAC0QLz6UCyhsn-poLwp`

So some things that are sure ( because some token are sending and same app, same server, same android studio, etc):

```
The Server Key is ok.
The Google Service Json is ok.
The token is copy/paste correctly
```

Can be some issue with some special character or a bug of Firebase? 
Thanks!!!